# React run a function or open a url in a new tab ternary

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a div, that is being populated with dynamic data. either an image, or text/pdf. I have it set up where if you click that div, it will open a carousel of images. For the text/pdf, i want it to take that url, and open it in a new tab.

The code:

```
example.map((item.index) => {
    <Grid container lg={12} onClick={item.contentType === 'image/jpeg' ? openSlider : <a href={item.url}></a>}>
})
```

the map is just for reference. inside the 'item' array, there is a contentType, and url.

The question is, i can get the left side to work and open the carousel, but when i click on a text file it does nothing. Im fairly certain the above code is wrong, but im not sure how to open a url via onClick without an  tag.

Comment: try `window.open(item.url)`

Comment: this just opens it immediately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
<Grid container lg={12} onClick={item.contentType === 'image/jpeg' ? openSlider : () => window.open(item.url)}>
```

window.open() opens a new tab at the desired url. You have to use a callback to say "onClick is a function that calls window.open" instead of "onClick is the result of window.open()".

Comment: <Grid container lg={12} onClick={item.contentType == 'image/jpeg' ? openSlider : () => openText(item)}> I used this, and put the window.open(ite,url) in a new function